# strace hang on system call read

Tags: ubuntu, strace

I exectued command: strace -ttt /bin/cat to get system calls on Ubuntu 11.04. However strace got hang on command "read" and could not finish.
 I have to press ctrl+c to stop it. 
The output is something like:

```
...
1365073129.724883 close(3)              = 0
1365073129.724928 fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
1365073129.724963 fstat64(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
1365073129.725003 read(0,
```

Since i need to do the same thing to a huge amount of executable files, I can not afford frequent hangs like this. Is there anyway to solve this problem, for example, make strace stop if time out, or make strace quit skip system call that got hung up.